# integerForKey: always returns zero

Tags: cocoa, macos, integer, nsuserdefaults

i'm trying to retrieve a value from my preference file which is an integer. The funny thing is that it always returns zero, although it does exist and the names for both `integerForKey:` and `setIntegerForKey:` are the same.

Here's how I retrieve the value: `[defaults integerForKey:@"BackUpSize"];`

And here I set it: `[defaults setInteger:[sizeSlider doubleValue]*8589934592 forKey:@"BackUpSize"];`

I'm stunned. It should work...or am I missing something here?

Thanks

Edit: defaults is created as such: `NSUserDefaults*defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`

Edit: I've tried creating my own NSUserDefaults method for this issue, but it still returns zero.

```
-(void)setDouble:(double)dou forKey:(id)key
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:dou] forKey:key];
}
-(double)doubleForKey:(id)key
{
    return [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key] doubleValue];
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `defaults` is not `nil`? Method-calls on `nil` return... `0`.

Comment: defaults is just [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]...

Comment: just verified it and it isn't nil.

Comment: Are both statements within the same class? Are you sending `setInteger:forKey:` *before* `integerForKey:`, or after? Are you quitting your application normally, or terminating it from Xcode?

Comment: setInteger:forKey: happens before its being read. I do quit the app normally since when done via xcode, no preferences are saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`8589934592` is a hard-coded literal? *Really?* You should at least put something like `1 << 33`. Even then, declare it as a constant, for crying out loud.

If you're building for 32 bit, `NSInteger` is a 32 bit signed value. So you are rather likely to be overflowing. I'm not sure what the behaviour of NSUserDefaults would be in that case, but it's worth considering.

Comment: I'm impressed that you recognized it as 1 << 33 on sight. ☺

Answer (score 1):

Another common cause of this sort of problem is using custom setters that store the values to user defaults.  If you do this, and if you aren't careful to access only the ivars in your user defaults code, you run the risk of stomping on the stored prefs while you're reading them.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a double into something that expects an integer. Normally you'd expect some truncation to occur, and to end up with an int, but you can't guarantee that the `setInteger:forKey:` method is doing that for you.

Why are you multiplying your slider value by that apparently arbitrary number?

Edit:

To explain my answer a little more:

In order to store numbers in the defaults they need to be wrapped in `NSNumber` objects. `setInteger:forKey`, et al, are convenience methods that probably just take your integer and create an `NSNnumber` from it, using `numberWithInt:`. I can't be 100% sure because I haven't seen Apple's code, but I'd assume that passing a double to `numberWithInt:` will return nil because a double is not an int.

Comment: the reason why i multiply it is because the slider needs to define how much space my app may use, which is defined in bytes in my case, but i need it in GB 1 byte times 8589934592 equals to 1GB. then i compare the folder size (which is also in bytes so i need to multiply it again) with the slider one to see if the limit has been reached or not. What should I use instead of setIntegerForKey? just use setObjectForKey?

Comment: I would suggest creating an `NSNumber` object from your final double value, using `numberWithDouble:` and then using `setObject:forKey`.

Comment: `setInteger` takes an NSInteger. I'm pretty sure the compiler should do the cast automatically; the object will *not* receive a double. It may not be great form to not make it explicit, but I don't think it's an error.

Comment: What walky said - you don't have to know Apples code for that, its a *language* feature.

Comment: the compiler shows no warning at all, i tried creating my own subclass `-(void)setDouble:(double)dou forKey:(id)key` and `-(double)doubleForKey:(id)key` but it still has the same result, even if i used NSNumber

Comment: David Schiefer: 1 GB is 1,000,000,000 (10^9) bytes, particularly on Snow Leopard, where the Finder now follows this definition. Even on previous versions of Mac OS X and on other OSs, 1 GB (or GiB) has never been 8,589,934,592 bytes; the correct definition was 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 1,073,741,824 bytes.

Comment: thanks for that Peter, I've changed my bytes value with your equation instead. could anyone suggest to me why even my custom NSUserDefaults implementation fails too? the odd thing is that when i want to update the NSSlider, it mysteriously works? `[sizeSlider setDoubleValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:@"BackUpSize"]/ 1024 / 1024 / 1024];` works fine :/